# How to Implement RBAC with Granular Permissions for Navigation Tabs in a Web Application?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, rbac

I'm in the process of integrating a Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) system into my web application and am looking for guidance on best practices and potential solutions.

Current Setup:

- The application has multiple tabs such as Homepage, Manager, Manage Employees, Manage Creators, Statistics, Growth Section, and Analytics.
- Roles are currently identified by name strings rather than by reference IDs.

Requirement:

- I need to implement a permission system that controls visibility and actions within these tabs based on the user's assigned role.
- For example, users with the "Employee" role should not have access to the Growth and Analytics tabs — these tabs should not even be visible to them.
- Furthermore, within the Manage Employees tab, "Employee" role users should be permitted to view the list of employees but should be restricted from adding or deleting employees.

Challenges:

- I need to establish a granular permission structure that not only restricts access to entire tabs but also to specific actions within those tabs.
- The system should be dynamic enough to easily update permissions and reflect those changes in the UI without the need for a page reload.

Question:

- How can I efficiently map these granular permissions to my existing role names?
- What are the best practices for handling permissions in the backend to support this kind of frontend RBAC system?
- How should I structure my permissions in the database to support this granularity while maintaining manageability and scalability?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question is very broad. Too broad to answer in one post. [Focus your question on one problem at a time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400968/what-does-it-mean-to-focus-on-one-problem-only). And when asking that question, provide your best guess at what you think will work and we can tell you if that will or will not work. For example, when asking "How should I structure my permissions in the database" try to create a schema yourself and put that in the question. That gives us a good starting point to provide an answer from.

Comment: @AlexWayne "I have incorporated a 'Parent Permission' field into the schema to streamline permission management. When I add a 'Manage Employee' permission, along with its sub-permissions such as 'Add Employee', I include the 'Manage Employee' permission ID in the 'Add Employee' permission. This approach simplifies the retrieval of all permissions related to this section."